# Target URL is not well-formed ERROR in Selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

This is my URL in object repository file

```
URL = https://www.google.co.in/
```

And this is my code

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 driver.get("URL");
```

> Getting error - Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Target URL URL is not
>   well-formed. Command duration or timeout: 43 milliseconds

Comment: What is your object repository? How is it organized? How do you get items from it?

Comment: what type of file are you using for a object repository is it .txt, .properties, .yml , .yaml, etc....

Answer (score 3):

Selenium's `driver.get` method expects the argument to be a URL, not a string. What you've entered is a string which is why the error has occured.

Try

```
driver.get(URL);
```

or simply

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Technically, the parameter to `driver.get()` is a string . . . it's just a matter of passing in the right string . . . .

Comment: He is trying to get the url that is stored on the object repository file. since he is  trying to read a value from a file. I don't think he can directly call the url variable.

Answer (score 0):

In repository...URL is already defined as String...so just use URL without quote...e.g.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get(URL);
```

If error didn't resolve through this...try

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
System.out.print(URL);
//driver.get(URL);
```

Verify whether `URL` contains the proper url which you have defined in object repository. Hoping this should resolve your issue.